# Check angular radio button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an angular modal with a pair of radio buttons and depending on the value of `quicklink` I want a certain button to be checked however neither of the buttons are checked until clicked on with mouse.

```
<label>
    <input name="quicklink" rows="3" type="radio" value="1" 
           ng-model="entity.quicklink" id="radio-1" />
    yes</label>
<label>
    <input name="quicklink" rows="3" type="radio" value="0" 
           ng-model="entity.quicklink" id="radio-2" />
    no</label>
```

```js
$scope.entity = data;
if ($scope.entity['quicklink'] == '1') {
    $("#radio-1").prop("checked", true)
}
if ($scope.entity['quicklink'] == '0') {
    $("#radio-2").prop("checked", true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For best practice, we should avoid calling DOM using jQuery directly from Angular.

Ideally, if *data* has valid *quicklink* value `{quicklink: '0'}`, you do not need to do anything.

http://plnkr.co/edit/98rog2BMCLXGfNtoWy1o

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope){

    $scope.entity = {quicklink: '0'};

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (without jQuery):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.entity = { quicklink: 1 };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>quicklink label</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input name="quicklink" rows="3" type="radio" value="1" class="form-control" ng-model="entity.quicklink" id="radio-1"/>
        yes</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input name="quicklink" rows="3" type="radio" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="entity.quicklink" id="radio-2"/>
      no</label>
  </div>

  <div>Value of quicklink is: {{entity.quicklink}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is that a js response? cause i cant run this in js it needs to come from my jquery file as on industrial project